# Can't run Anchor test with the basic project

Tags: anchor, anchor-test, solana-test-validator

I just created an Anchor project with `anchor init` and tried to run `anchor test` but it didn't work. I always get the error:

`Unable to get latest blockhash. Test validator does not look started. Check .anchor/test-ledger/test-ledger-log.txt for errors. Consider increasing [test.startup_wait] in Anchor.toml.`

If I try using `solana-test-validator` I get the error `Error: failed to start validator: Failed to create ledger at test-ledger: blockstore error`

I increased the `startup_wait` value in Anchor.toml file but it didn't work as well:

```
[test]
startup_wait = 100000
```

My log file shows the following:

```
INFO [0m solana_test_validator[0m[38;5;8m][0m solana-validator 1.15.2 (src:94dd3726; feat:1211687720, client:SolanaLabs)
INFO [0m solana_test_validator[0m[38;5;8m][0m Starting validator with: ArgsOs {
        inner: [
            "solana-test-validator",
        ],
    }
WARN [0m solana_perf[0m[38;5;8m][0m CUDA is disabled
INFO [0m solana_perf[0m[38;5;8m][0m AVX detected
INFO [0m solana_perf[0m[38;5;8m][0m AVX2 detected
INFO [0m solana_faucet::faucet[0m[38;5;8m][0m Faucet started. Listening on: 0.0.0.0:9900
INFO [0m solana_faucet::faucet[0m[38;5;8m][0m Faucet account address: GbS4pJsmhizfuvYJhm8sMSQ3xRHDHbUWCTNkkXygVC1Q
INFO [0m solana_ledger::blockstore[0m[38;5;8m][0m Maximum open file descriptors: 1000000
INFO [0m solana_ledger::blockstore[0m[38;5;8m][0m Opening database at "test-ledger/rocksdb"
INFO [0m solana_ledger::blockstore[0m[38;5;8m][0m "test-ledger/rocksdb" open took 108ms
INFO [0m solana_metrics::metrics[0m[38;5;8m][0m metrics disabled: SOLANA_METRICS_CONFIG: environment variable not found
INFO [0m solana_metrics::metrics[0m[38;5;8m][0m datapoint: shred_insert_is_full total_time_ms=0i slot=0i last_index=3i num_repaired=0i num_recovered=0i
INFO [0m solana_runtime::hardened_unpack[0m[38;5;8m][0m Extracting "test-ledger/genesis.tar.bz2"...
```

The versions I'm using are:

```
anchor-cli 0.26.0
solana-test-validator 1.15.2
rustc 1.67.0
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Try this combination:

```
rustc 1.65.0
solana-cli 1.14.12
anchor-cli 0.26.0
```

Solana 1.15 doesn't seem to currently work with Anchor 0.26. Was also getting errors when upgrading to Anchor 0.26 and found a working combo by referencing the versions used on Solpg.

Comment: Hi John, I tried, but unfortunately, it didn't work as well. Still stuck on this. :-(

Comment: This is correct. There was an issue with the 1.15.2 release, so be sure to re-install the earlier versions until 1.15.3 is released using `solana-install init 1.14.12` and also using the 1.14.12 crates